# How to update a table using "NOW()" from database in prisma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, typescript, prisma

I don't want use the date of my api server, how can I use a raw function from database? Thank you
Example (when I set finishedAt):

```
    await ctx.prisma.serviceOrder.updateMany({
  data: {
    status,
    finishedAt: status === ServiceOrderStatus.CONCLUDED ? ctx.prisma.raw("NOW()") : null
  },
  where: {
    id,
    finishedAt: null,
  },
});
```

Comment: There is a [github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1831) possibly helpful?

Comment: Prisma stores all dates in UTC and converts them appropriately before querying, so you shouldn't have any time related issues even if you use the date from the API server. If that is your main motivation for using the database server time, I would suggest not worrying about it as it's a non-issue.